# SQL Server - monthly avg of count

Tags: sql-server, date, count, average

I want to be able to find out the monthly average of a count

My code at the moment is

```
SELECT 
    company, 
    COUNT(company) AS 'count'
FROM Information
GROUP BY company
```

I basically need it to be

```
SELECT company, 
       count(company) as 'count'
       avg(count(company)) per month as 'average'
FROM Information
group by company
```

I want the result to look something like this

```
company count   monthly average
a       5       6
b       13      14
c       2       2
d       45      45
e       23      21
f       6       5
```

Comment: what field you have date/month information?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected result. You show us some expected result but dont say from where you get that.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza start_date

Comment: You didnt read my comment, we need sample data and db schema

Comment: Do you simply want to look at an information record's month and count records per month? Usually one would treat the first month and the last month different from the rest. E.g. data starts on April 1 with 21 records for April, continues with May and 21 records and ends today with zero records for June so far. Would the avarage be 42/3 or rather 42/2, as we cannot consider June yet? 42/2 would seem more realistic, but is harder to calculate. You sample data however seems to imply this (with the monthly avarage being higher than the total count for some companies).

Comment: `'count'` is a string by the way. Don't you get a syntax error? For names it should be `"count"` in standard SQL and `[count]` in SQL Server.

Comment: `count(company)` looks very strange, because it is of course not companies your are counting. `count(*)` would look much more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach would be to count per company and month first and then aggregate this data to get total and avarage per company.

```
select
  company,
  sum(cnt) as records,
  avg(cnt) as records_per_month
from
(
  select company, year(start_date), month(start_date), count(*) as cnt
  from information
  group by company, year(start_date), month(start_date)
) agg
group by company;
```

But read my comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(yourDate) * 100 + MONTH(yourDate) YYMM,
        company, 
        count(company) as 'count'
        avg(count(company)) per month as 'average'
FROM Information
group by company
,YEAR(yourDate) * 100 + MONTH(yourDate)
```

Comment: you can of course apply more sophisticated formatting to the YEAR & MONTH, I'm just churning out a 201606 style record for speed of illustration