# Calculating Average by Month / Year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate the average number of records per month, but my sample code below is not working properly.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I've checked a few other questions such as [SQL Server - monthly avg of count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594746/sql-server-monthly-avg-of-count) but it doesn't work for me.

```
Create Table #TestData
(
    DateCreated datetime,
    Number int 
)

Insert into #TestData
(
    DateCreated,
    Number
)
SELECT
    '26 Nov 2018',
    '10'
UNION
SELECT
    '26 Nov 2018',
    '11'
UNION
SELECT
    '27 Nov 2018',
    '10'
UNION
SELECT
    '28 Nov 2018',
    '11'
UNION
SELECT
    '29 Nov 2018',
    '20'
UNION
SELECT
    '30 Nov 2018',
    '35'
UNION
SELECT
    '01 Dec 2018',
    '35'
UNION
SELECT
    '02 Dec 2018',
    '40'
UNION
SELECT
    '02 Dec 2018',
    '75'

select 
    month,
    year,
    cnt,
    avg(cnt) as avg
from
(
select 
    MONTH(DateCreated) AS [month],
    YEAR(DateCreated) AS [year],
    count(*) as cnt
from 
    #TestData
group by
    MONTH(DateCreated),
    YEAR(DateCreated)
) agg
group by
    cnt,
    month,
    year

drop table #TestData
```

Comment: .... `GROUP BY cnt, month year`, but your previous level has `GROUP BY month, year`, which means you can only have one `(month, year)`, tuple.  Did you add an extra level or something?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I don't have those two sets of group bys, I can't use count(*) or avg(cnt)

Comment: The `cnt` in the outer `group by` (and `select`) is what you've done wrong. Remove that from the outer query and you'll get the results you want.

Comment: @ZoharPeled , would you mind posting that as an answer? I have removed cnt from the outer query and no difference, still not getting the correct average.

Comment: I've got 6 for November and 3 for December based on the sample data you've posted. What is your expected result? (could it be 4.5 by any chance?)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - shouldn't the average for Nov be 1.2 as there's 6 rows across 5 days, and for Dec 3 rows across 3 days making the average 1.

Comment: So you want the average record count per day for each month?

Comment: @Philip Sorry but i didn't understand what you're looking. 
If all off november row's was posted on 26 Nov 2018 your're exprected (4 as the average :o ? )

I didn't the relevent explain off that average it's doesn't have sense ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, seems like you want an average of the daily record count for each month - Here's a small modification to your code from the question to get that:

```
select 
     MONTH(DateCreated) As month,
     YEAR(DateCreated) As year,
     avg(cast(cnt as float)) as avg -- cast as float otherwise you'll get an integer result
from
(
    select 
        CAST(DateCreated As Date) AS DateCreated,
        count(*) as cnt
    from 
        #TestData
    group by
        CAST(DateCreated As Date) -- group by days
) agg
group by
     MONTH(DateCreated),
     YEAR(DateCreated)
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use window functions this should work

```
select #TestData.*
    ,average = avg(number) over (partition by convert(varchar(7), DateCreated, 120)) 
from #TestData
```

OR

```
select #TestData.*
,average = avg(number) over (partition by year(DateCreated), month(DateCreated))
from #TestData
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9520526cd9e3e1df196e12118909856d)